# jQuery pagination and dropdown not working together

Tags: jquery, pagination

I'm working on a page that has a list of press releases broken out by year. The page has a dropdown that defaults to the current year, but the user can also choose a previous year. I'm using a show/hide with the dropdown to display the selected list. This part is working.

I've also added the easypagination plugin, so that for each year only the first four press releases are displayed with the option to click on "OLDER" link or page numbers at the bottom of the page. The problem is that only the first year from the dropdown that uses pagination (in this example 2012 since 2013 only has 3 press releases). 2012 works perfectly, but if you go to 2011, it works but the class="current" never gets to that ‹li› and the current bottom page numbers is never highlighted.

My question is how do I change my code so that when the user hits the dropdown, the function recognizes that action resets and appends the class="current" to the correct first ‹li›?

Here's the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brianjschneider/GjXJR/

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I think the problem/solution is somewhere in this function:

```
$.fn.easyPaginate = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
        step: 4,
        delay: 0,
        numeric: true,
        nextprev: true,
        auto: false,
        loop: false,
        pause: 10000,
        clickstop: true,
        controls: 'pagination',
        current: 'current',
        randomstart: false
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var step = options.step;
    var lower, upper;
    var children = $(this).children();
    var count = children.length;
    var obj, next, prev;
    var pages = Math.floor(count / step);
    var page = (options.randomstart) ? Math.floor(Math.random() * pages) + 1 : 1;
    var timeout;
    var clicked = false;

    function show() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        lower = ((page - 1) * step);
        upper = lower + step;
        $(children).each(function (i) {
            var child = $(this);
            child.hide();
            if (i >= lower && i < upper) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    child.fadeIn('fast')
                }, (i - (Math.floor(i / step) * step)) * options.delay);
            }
            if (options.nextprev) {
                if (upper >= count) {
                    next.fadeOut('fast');
                } else {
                    next.fadeIn('fast');
                };
                if (lower >= 1) {
                    prev.fadeIn('fast');
                } else {
                    prev.fadeOut('fast');
                };
            };
        });
        $('li', '#' + options.controls).removeClass(options.current);
        $('li[data-index="' + page + '"]', '#' + options.controls).addClass(options.current);

        if (options.auto) {
            if (options.clickstop && clicked) {} else {
                timeout = setTimeout(auto, options.pause);
            };
        };
    };
```

Comment: Looks like the plugin has a scope problem. It's updating the current page for 2012 even when you're on 2011.

Comment: I think you're right. I believe something needs to be refreshed in the function show(), but I can't quite figure out how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of time to help. You'll need to pass the clicked element to the plugin.

Comment: That's where I'm having my problem. I know handleYearSelection function is what determines which year to show, so I'm trying to pass that value to the plugin. I think it belongs somewhere in 'function show()' but I can't figure out the way to target it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anybody want to take another look? I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!